# LibraryFunctionLoad and PATH

Tags: python, python-embedding

I'm using the python-c api with LibraryLink. How can I specify which exact  python interpreter I would like to be used?

Currently, the wrong executable is being used:

[image]

which gives the wrong one:

```
(* sys.executable = /usr/bin/python *)
```

With what option can I change this, and when - during the call to `CreateLibrary` or from inside `LoadLibraryFunction`?

**What I've tried:**

- playing with `SetEnvironment` and friends
- playing with the "Include*" options of CreateLibrary
- setting the env path in `WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData)`

Comment: I am afraid this is not a Mathematica question, but a Python one, and thus off topic.  You are using some sort of API to access Python.  Have you checked the documentation of this API to see which interpreter it uses, or how you can select an interpreter?  Why do you believe that the solution to the problem concerns Mathematica or LibraryLink and not the specific Python embedding API you are using?

Comment: I searched a little bit and found this: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding  "The `Py_SetProgramName()` function should be called before `Py_Initialize()` to inform the interpreter about paths to Python run-time libraries. "

Comment: You probably need to initialize a virtual environment and then run your script. `sys.executable` will then give you the correct python interpreter.

Comment: @Szabolcs Py_SetProgramName doesn't set the interpreter. Also sometimes I get  `"sys.executable = \
/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel",` which is bizzare

Comment: You are right, that function doesn't set an interpreter.  I was confused by the wording of the documentation.  Looking more carefully, it looks like the interpreter binary is embedded (i.e. linked to statically).  So a `python` executable is never invoked as a separate process in this case.  Here's how to ensure which one is linked: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#compiling-and-linking-under-unix-like-systems  This means that `sys.executable` *should* really be WolframKernel, because the python interpreter is running inside of the WolframKernel process now.

Comment: There's this for controlling which packages/libraries python will use: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPythonHome  I still think that this is a python question, not a Mathematica one.  The expertise needed is about how to embed python in any program, and the details about embedding in Mathematica probably don't matter at all.  There will be many more people here on SO capable of answering the question.  Personally I don't know anything about this topic other than what I found in the python docs ...

Comment: Wait, but Py_SetPythonHome only changes PYTHONHOME, which doesn't affect the python interpreter being used.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  See my previous comment on the interpreter.